# Let $FG$ be a group ring. For a reducible $FG-$module,$ V,$ and $U$ a $G-$invariant subspace, how can we enlarge our basis to a basis of $V?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

For a field $F$ and a finite group $G$ consider the group ring $FG.$ Suppose $U$ is a $G-$invariant subspace of $V$ as above. My book says we can form a basis of $V$ by taking a basis of $U$ and enlarging it to a basis of $V$ in the following way. For each $g \in G$ the matrix $\phi(g),$ of $g$ acting on $V$ with respect to this basis is of the form $\phi(g) = \begin{pmatrix} 
\phi_1(g) & \psi(g) \\
0 & \phi_2(g) 
\end{pmatrix}$ where $\phi_1 = \phi \mid_U$ and $\phi_2$ is the representation of $G$ on $V/U.$ How do we know it is of this form?

Answer (score 0):

By hypothesis $U$ is invariant, so $\phi_1(u) \in U$ for all $u \in U$, which means exactly that if we take a basis $u_1, \dots, u_r$ of $U$ and complete it into a basis of $V$, then $\phi(u_i) = \sum_1^r \lambda_{ij} u_j$, which is equivalent to say that the matrix of $\phi$ is on the form that you wrote.

Comment: What about the portion of the matrix that doesn't correspond to the action of $\phi$ on $U$? That is, the last few columns?

Comment: This portition is the right part of the matrix. Moreover, if $x \notin U$ then $\phi(g)x = \psi(g)(x)u' + \phi_2(g)w' $ so indeed the action on $V/U$ is given by $\phi_2$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how $\psi$ is determined? Your explanation seems to be echoing the claim without much explanation as to why. Thanks

Comment: @AOrtiz : Well, for simplicity let's take $V$ two dimensional and $U$ to be one dimensional, spanned by $u$. Take a basis $(u,w)$ of $V$. By hypothesis $\phi(g)(u) = \lambda_1(g) u$ and $\phi(g)(w) = \mu_1(g)u + \mu_2(g)w$. On the quotient $V/U = W$ we have $\phi(g)w = \mu_2(g)w$ as expected. $\psi(g)$ is $\mu_1(g)$ by construction. The general case it works exactly the same.